# why doesn't fluentd write logs to the right directory?

Tags: fluentd

**my task:**

1. is to collect access.log nginx
2. to divide the nginx logs by codes
3. if the response code is from 1xx to 3xx, then write to /tmp/1xx-3xx
4. if the response code is from 4xx to 5xx, then /tmp/4xx-5xx

since I'm new to fluentd, I can't figure out where my error is?

**td-agent.conf:**

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id input_tail
  <parse>
    @type nginx
  </parse>
  path /var/log/nginx/access.log
  tag nginx
</source>

<match nginx.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key code
    pattern /([1-5][0-9]{2})/
    tag nginx.$1
  </rule>
</match>

<match {nginx.4**,nginx.5**}>
  @type file
  path /tmp/4xx-5xx
</match>

<match {nginx.1**,nginx.2**,nginx.3**}>
  @type file
  path /tmp/1xx-3xx
</match>
```

Comment: Have you observed any errors in fluentd logs?

Comment: nothing unusual is observed in the logs

Comment: Tested your config with `tail`'s `read_from_head true` and it works fine. According to [file](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file) input plugin, the files are not created immediately. For an immediate test, you can add `buffer` section with `flush_mode immediate` and test it. Later, you can configure it according to your own time requirements. See https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section#flushing-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

error with permission /var/log/nginx/access.log
solution
chmod 0644 /var/log/nginx/access.log